# Problem with code including structures but I have no idea why (C)

Tags: c, struct

So, I'm kind of a beginner, and I was learning about structures so I decided to try making a program that takes the length of 2 distances in metres and centimetres but it skips getting an input for the meter value of the second distance. The code I used is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct distance{
    int meter;
    float centimeter;
}l1,l2,sum;

int main()
{
    printf("Distance 1 : \n");
    printf("Enter the meter value :");
    scanf("%d",&l1.meter);
    printf("Enter the centimeter value :");
    scanf("%.2f",&l1.centimeter);

    printf("Distance 2 : \n");
    printf("Enter the meter value : \n");
    scanf("%d",&l2.meter);
    printf("Enter the centimeter value :");
    scanf("%.2f",&l2.centimeter);



    sum.meter = l1.meter + l2.meter;
    sum.centimeter = l1.centimeter + l2.centimeter;

    while(sum.centimeter >= 100)
    {
        ++sum.meter;
        sum.centimeter-=100;
    }

    printf("The sum of the distances you have entered is %d m and %f cm.",sum.meter,sum.centimeter);
    return 0;

}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't read the compiler warnings. `%.2f` is not a valid format for `scanf`, use `%f`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see any compiler warnings though, maybe because of my IDE? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're using an invalid format specifier in `scanf("%.2f"...)`. Instead, you can use `scanf("%f"...)`. However, maybe you would want to turn on compiler warnings. Here is the relevant warning I got on my machine :

> ```
> warning: invalid conversion specifier '.' [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]
>
> scanf("%.2f",&l2.centimeter);
>         ~^
> ```